# My firebase app stops working the moment I try to open it

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I am developing a simple login signup app using react native, firebase and react navigation. But every time I compile the code and try to run the app on my app, it says "AppName stopped working" and I do "open app again" then "AppName keeps stopping". I am not sure what the issue is... I would be deeply grateful if you can help me resolve the issue.
Code: https://github.com/EthereousNatsuDragneel/Midnight

I am a blind developer and sorry I am new to stackoverflow and not sure how to mark answers as accepted. But I appretiate every answer from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Hey Natsu. Please make sure that your question includes the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That makes is much more like that someone can (and will) help. In addition, if your app crashes there should be an error message and stack trace in the logcat output. Please find those, and add them to your question too. Adding both of these makes is much more like that someone can (and will) help.

Comment: Hey Frank. Usually it shows me to view logs, but in this case the only option I have is "close the app". And I am not sure where the error lies so I put a link to my code. The entire code is not too big.